# How to create a Drawer Component and adding it to multiple screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Hi i want to create a component by using a `createDrawerNavigator`, and want to add it all screens could you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In the below example don't copy all the syntax understand the concept from my explanation I have configured redux and many other imports you may not need so configure and include content in below files as you need.**

**File name - `BurgerMenu.js`**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SideBar from "./SideBar.js";
import News from "../../Containers/News";  // import your screens instead
import Copyright from '../../Containers/Gallery' // import your screens instead
import { DrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";

const BurgerMenu = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    News: { screen: News },
    RulesOfUse: { screen: RulesOfUse },
    Copyright: { screen: Copyright }
  },
  {
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
  }
);

export default BurgerMenu;
```

**File name - `SideBar.js`**

**In this file specify the layout, any actions like navigation, api call etc of drawer as you want which is imported to above `BurgerMenu.js` file**

```
 /*
    SideBar.js

    Component used to render contents of SideBar
*/

import React from 'react';
import { View, Modal, Text, Linking } from 'react-native';

const {
    modalBackground,
    topContentStyle,
    bottomContentStyle
} = styles;

class SideBar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    render() {
        return (
               <View
                    elevation={5}
                    style={modalBackground}
                >

                </View>
        );
    }
  }

export default SideBar;
```

**And in the `App.js` import `Burgermenu.js` to `StackNavigator`**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Splash from './src/App/Containers/Splash';
import Login from './src/App/Containers/Login';
import InformationPage from './src/App/Containers/Gallery'
import BurgerMenu from './src/App/Components/BurgerMenu/index'
import configureStore from './src/RNRedux/ConfigureStore';


// Manifest of possible screens
const PrimaryNav = StackNavigator({
  Splash: { screen: Splash },
  Login: { screen: Login },
  Home: { screen: BurgerMenu },
  InformationPage: { screen: InformationPage }
 }, {
    // Default config for all screens
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'Splash',
  });

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      channelId: ""
    };
    this.store = configureStore();
  }

  componentDidMount() {

  }

  componentWillMount() {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={this.store}>
        <PrimaryNav />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**Just open the burger menu from any the screens imported to** `BurgerMenu.js`

**In my example you can open it from `news.js` and `gallery.js` which are imported to `BurgerMenu.js`.**

**Just use below functions for open and close**

```
openBurgerMenu() {
        this.props.navigation.openDrawer();
    }

closeBurgerMenu() {
        this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();
    }
```