# DrawerNavigator from another file is not working

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I have following code in App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View,} from 'react-native';
import{DrawerNavigator, DrawerActions} from 'react-navigation';


import { Menu} from './src/components/menu';

 export default class MainView extends Component {
   render(){
     return(
       <View>
       <Menu />
          <Text>  WHAT ??? </Text>
       </View>
     );
   }
 }
```

and following code in src/components/menu.js

```js
'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import{DrawerNavigator, DrawerActions} from 'react-navigation';


export  class Menu extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <View style= {styles.navContainer}>
        <View style= {styles.navContainerFlexing}>
          <View>
            <Icon name="bars" size={25} color= 'black' style={{marginLeft: 10, fontWeight: '200' }}  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}  />
         </View>
          <Text style={[styles.whiteText, styles.navItem]}>Home</Text>
      </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export  const Drawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Menu: Menu,
  },
  {
    // initialRouteName: 'Home',
  },
  {
    drawerPosition: 'left',
   initialRouteName: 'Home',
   drawerBackgroundColor: 'white',
   drawerWidth: 300,

 }
 );

const styles= StyleSheet.create({
  navContainer: {
    height: 55,
    backgroundColor: '#3ba558',
    alignItems: 'center',
    // flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    // justifyContent: 'flex-start'
  },
  navContainerFlexing: {
    flex: 2,
    flexDirection: 'row',
      backgroundColor: '#3ba558',
      paddingLeft: 20
  },
  whiteText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
  navItem: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 'auto',
    marginBottom: 'auto',
    marginLeft: 10

  },
});
```

Now I want my Menu class to display in App.js, which is displaying but and I also want it workable DrawerNavigator in homepage, right now the drawer is giving:

```
 undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.dispatch')
```

Answer (score 0):

I Have explained the configuration of `DrawerNavigator` in the below `link`.

Look into the accepted answer in the below `link`.

[How to create a Drawer Component and adding it to multiple screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149677/how-to-create-a-drawer-component-and-adding-it-to-multiple-screens/53150451#53150451)

As I explained in it **try to understand the concept and do not copy the syntax**.

**Do a comparison with your configuration, you will find your problem.**